# Implement simple architecture using Akka Graphs

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I’m attempting to setup a simple graph structure that process data via invoking rest services, forwards the result of each service to an intermediary processing unit before forwarding the result. Here is a high level architecture :

[image]

Can this be defined using Akka graph streams ? Reading https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html I don't understand how to even implement this simple architecture.

I've tried to implement custom code to execute functions within a graph :

```
package com.graph

class RestG {

  def flow (in : String) : String = {
    return in + "extra"
  }

}

object RestG {

  case class Flow(in: String) {

    def out : String = in+"out"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    List(new RestG().flow("test") , new RestG().flow("test2")).foreach(println)

  }

}
```

I'm unsure how to send data between the functions. So I think I should be using Akka Graphs but how to implement the architecture above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem.  First some types:

```
type Data = Int
type RestService1Response = String
type RestService2Response = String
type DisplayedResult = Boolean
```

Then stub functions to asynchronously call the external services:

```
def callRestService1(data: Data): Future[RestService1Response] = ???
def callRestService2(data: Data): Future[RestService2Response] = ???
def resultCombiner(resp1: RestService1Response, resp2: RestService2Response): DisplayedResult = ???
```

Now for the Akka Streams (I'm leaving out setting up an `ActorSystem` etc.)

```
import akka.Done
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

type SourceMatVal = Any
val dataSource: Source[Data, SourceMatVal] = ???

def restServiceFlow[Response](callF: Data => Future[Data, Response], maxInflight: Int) = Flow[Data].mapAsync(maxInflight)(callF)

// NB: since we're fanning out, there's no reason to have different maxInflights here...
val service1 = restServiceFlow(callRestService1, 4)
val service2 = restServiceFlow(callRestService2, 4)

val downstream = Flow[(RestService1Response, RestService2Response)]
  .map((resultCombiner _).tupled)

val splitAndCombine = GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val fanOut = b.add(Broadcast[Data](2))
  val fanIn = b.add(Zip[RestService1Response, RestService2Response])

  fanOut.out(0).via(service1) ~> fanIn.in0
  fanOut.out(1).via(service2) ~> fanIn.in1

  FlowShape(fanOut.in, fanIn.out)
}

// This future will complete with a `Done` if/when the stream completes
val future: Future[Done] = dataSource
  .via(splitAndCombine)
  .via(downstream)
  .runForeach { displayableData =>
    ??? // Display the data
  }
```

It's possible to do all the wiring within the Graph DSL, but I generally prefer to keep my graph stages as simple as possible and only use them to the extent that the standard methods on `Source`/`Flow`/`Sink` can't do what I want.